# PhantomJS driver wont start

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I'm having issues starting up the PhantomJS driver. It works just fine on my local machine (OSX) but I'm having issues getting it started on the server (Linux).

Here's the code that causes the issue:

```
DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
String[] phantomArgs = new  String[] { "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE" };
dcap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);
dcap.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcap);
```

And here's the stack trace of the issue:

```
[ERROR] [09/09/2015 18:32:45.517] [pipeline-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-11] [akka://pipeline/user/$u] Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
        at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:110)
        at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:99)
        at com.example.p.Test.ingest(GoogleGetLinksPipe.java:48)
        at com.example.p.Test.ingest(GoogleGetLinksPipe.java:22)
        at com.example.p.AbstractPipe.onReceive(AbstractPipe.java:39)
        at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:167)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
        at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:97)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
        at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSCommandExecutor.execute(PhantomJSCommandExecutor.java:78)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:8092/status] to be available after 20000 ms
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
        ... 24 more
```

I built the PhantomJS from source and had it working before - it ran through the tests just fine. Additionally, it works locally on my machine. Any thoughts on what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Did you build the binary separately for OSX and for Linux?

Comment: @SiKing Yes - I download the binary for OSX and built from source on the linux server.

Comment: So then how do you know the one you built works? What happens if you run `./phantomjs --version` from command line? Also: what is the benefit of building it from scratch?

Comment: @SiKing It was working a day or two ago - not sure why it's not working now. And there is no distributed binary for linux, you have to build it from scratch for that OS.

Comment: @SiKing, The same error comes up with versions 2.0.1 and 1.9.8.

Comment: This http://phantomjs.org/download.html leads to this https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads Also, have you considered using this: https://github.com/Ardesco/selenium-standalone-server-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to the phantomjs's inability to write to the log file. Changing the file permissions of the log file resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I moved the log file location with the `--webdriver-logfile` option, and that did the trick.